# Some examples of @nogc incompatibility is not desirable?

Tags: d

A Dlang [gem](https://tour.dlang.org/tour/en/gems/attributes) writes about `@nogc`. FYI,  I haven't seen why '@nogc' should exist and this code is not desirable in `@nogc` mindset:

```
void foo() {
    auto a = new A;
}
```

And as the gem says, it causes error when one tries to use `@nogc` with it:

```
void foo() @nogc {
  // ERROR:
    auto a = new A;
}
```

So my question:
Can you give some examples of why this approach is bad, and a `@nogc` compatible equivalent version?

### Update 20170418:

A more realistic example. I am trying to port a [rather light-weight C header](https://github.com/attractivechaos/klib/blob/master/kseq.h) file to high quality D version (good balance of readability/maintainability, usability and performance). I've posted a related question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354980/c-to-d-struct-as-type-and-initialize). As one may see, this struct does not allow `@nogc` attribute because it does `new` to allocate memory. Watching the talk by [Walter Bright](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znjesAXEEqw) suggested by @rcorre gave a strong impression that I should go with `range`. But I don't know how to implement this yet. I also would like to clarify that this attempt to explore for high quality D code is not a kind of 'early optimization' mindset. I want to do it to get into good habits as early as possible so that I can avoid fixing many problems in later time points.

```
struct Kstream(T) {
    ubyte[] buf;
    int begin, end, is_eof;
    T f;

    this(T f, ubyte bs)
    {
        this.f = f;
        this.buf = new ubyte[bs];
    }

    ~this()
    {
      writeln("Destroyed struct.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Garbage collection can be a performance concern in real-time applications such as games, where it may manifest as a periodic "stutters" whenever collection occurs.

There are a few approaches you can take to writing `@nogc` code:

1. Don't. Unless you know you need to optimize, `@nogc` will be a pain.
2. Avoid allocations altogether. Use `struct` instead of `class`, static arrays instead of dynamic arrays, ect.
3. Manage your own menmory using `malloc` and `free` as you would in C instead of using `new` as you would in "typical" D code. This will most likely result in code that is more complicated and error prone, but might be appropriate if you are porting code from C.
4. Manage your own memory using [`std.experimental.allocator`](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_experimental_allocator.html). Note that it is `experimental`.

Programming without the GC can be more difficult and is often not necessary, but there are some habits you can develop that avoid spurious allocations without complicating your code. Walter Bright gave a [good presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znjesAXEEqw) on how programming with a range-based mindset can avoid the need for allocation.

Comment: Thanks @rcorre. The presentation does gave a good perspective, but I need some more practical examples.

Comment: I've edited to add more info, but it is hard to give practical examples without understanding what you are doing. In the example given above, you could manually allocate the array or use a static array sized to be 'big enough' for whatever you need, but neither of those may be a "good" solution. Maybe your Kstream can be a range that lazily serves up data. It is hard to say without a more complete understanding of the goal.